# How do I use configSource with configBuilders in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I'm following https://jeffreyfritz.com/2017/11/modern-configuration-for-asp-net-4-7-1-with-configurationbuilders/ for my ASP.NET 4.7.2 application but we have this in the Web.config:

`<connectionStrings configSource="myconfig.config"/>`

I was hoping I could transiently set the values in myconfig.config using environment variables by changing this block to:

`<connectionStrings configBuilders="Env" configSource="myconfig.config"/>`

But this gives me a compiler error:

`A section using 'configSource' may contain no other attributes or elements.`

Here's what myconfig.config looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="db1" connectionString="conn1" providerName="prov1" />
    <add name="db2" connectionString="conn2" providerName="prov2" />
    <add name="db3" connectionString="conn3" providerName="prov3" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Any ideas? I've been trying to search up how to make the two work in conjuction to no avail!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution, for anyone facing this, is to put the "configBuilders" attribute on the target file as so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<connectionStrings configBuilders="Env">
    <add name="db1" connectionString="conn1" providerName="prov1" />
    <add name="db2" connectionString="conn2" providerName="prov2" />
    <add name="db3" connectionString="conn3" providerName="prov3" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Also, because another issue popped up after.. make sure you are using "configSource" as an attribute and not "file".

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.